# Loading Coldfusion javascript asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coldfusion

Whenever a page is loaded with Coldfusion, it loads many default Coldfusion javascripts.  When I run the Goolge PageSpeed Tools, it always complain about the render-blocking JavaScript.  Apparently, Coldfusion has many javascript when a page is loaded such as

```
...scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js
...scripts/ajax/yui/aniax/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js
...scripts/ajax/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js
...scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js
...scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js
...scripts/ajax/package/cfautosuggest.js
...scripts/cfform.js
...scripts/masks.js
```

These all are considered render-blocking scripts. I can't find any information on how to make them none-render-blocking because obviously I can't add the async="async" parameter to the Coldfusion script which I can't see.  How can I make the Coldfusion script none-render-blocking or am I stuck with it?

Can someone please shed some lights?

Comment: *Whenever a page is loaded with Coldfusion,it loads many default Coldfusion javascripts*  Not true. The scripts are included only IF the page uses CF UI components. The includes are generated by the CF server internally. It is not something you can control, AFAIK. Anyway, regardless of what google says, you should avoid using CF UI components, which are outdated, buggy and difficult to customize IMO.

Comment: you might want to have a look at https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way

Comment: I would suggest you stop using the ColdFusion UI components. They are out of date, poorly implemented and woefully limited in functionality. In many cases you can accomplish the same thing easier with other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Looks like no one likes CF UI.  I use it due to its simplicity. I haven't actually use anything else.  Everything else is extra coding which I didn't have the expertise of doing.  That's the main reason.  The one I use the most is CFFORM validation.  The CFFORM by Raymond at [https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html](https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html) is incomplete so I can't use it.  Is there a complete set of UI for CFFORM else where?

Comment: *Looks like no one likes CF UI.* Honestly it is because of things like this ;-) Yes, they are easy to use initially. However, invariably you run into bugs and customization issues that are difficult to overcome due to the implementation and age of the underlying libraries (just search the archives). While google's recommendations here are low on the list of issues, it is still a good illustration of the inherent limitations of the CF UI stuff. While technically possible, it requires a lot of convoluted hoop jumping. Using another library, this would be a snap...

Comment: @Leigh can you recommend some complete UI replacement libraries?

Comment: The "UI the Right Way" project is the only pre-packaged stuff I know of. Anything beyond that is DIY.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to do something about this instead of rewriting your UI code, you can actually grab the output from the buffer before it is sent to the client and modify it. Your modifications could be as simple as removing a hardcoded list of script tags and replacing them with a custom script file that you host in your webroot. The custom script file would simply be all of the other script files' contents combined.

To do this:

1. In onRequestEnd in application.cfc you can call `var outputBuffer = getPageContext().popBody().getBuffer()` which will return the body to be sent to the client.
2. Run replacements on `outputBuffer`, looking for those script tags and removing them via regular expressions. You'll want to keep track of whether or not you've actually removed any to use as a flag in the next step.
3. Finally, you would append to the output with your new master script tag if your flag that replacements have been made is true. After you do that, the buffer will be automatically flushed to the client.

I believe that Adobe no longer updates the script files, so you basically don't have to worry about versioning your master script file to clear the browser cache.

Edit/Note: Definitely avoid using the CF UI stuff, but we don't know what your situation is like right now. If you have hundreds or thousands of hours of rewriting to do, then obviously rewriting it all is likely not something that is practical at this time.